# What's a good tutorial for creating a gem with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I've been searching around for ways to create a gem with RSpec, but haven't found descriptive tutorials.

I started out with [Ryan Bates' Making a gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/135-making-a-gem), but I'm looking for a tutorial that discusses creating an acts_as style gem with RSpec.

By acts_as, I mean to say that the gem adds certain methods to an existing class in Rails. Why is this important? Because I've found gem templates like New Gem, got a spec to run but when I try to test an Active Record object it starts choking. I've tried requiring active_record in spec_helper.rb but I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't solve the problem.

When it comes to plugins, I found [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#tests). If there's a gem version for that around that'd be awesome.

Thanks guys!

P.S. I love screencasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should have an answer about [Bundler](http://bundler.io/).

As much as I know, Bundler is -maybe- the most popular and used tool for easily creating gem skeletons.

And here is a great tutorial about it:

http://rakeroutes.com/blog/lets-write-a-gem-part-one/

Comment: I use bundler now. I like how small and simple the gemspec is.

Answer (score 13):

I like using [jeweler](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler#readme) for starting gems.

to generate a gem skeleton with rspec

```
jeweler --rspec my-gem-with-rspec
```

Comment: Thanks! This is like New Gem's rspec option. 

What I wanted to find was a tutorial that explain what I had to include and where. I ended up guessing what to include by copying and pasting stuff from different gems, and renaming them appropriately. It was a bit more haphazard than I would have liked but I suppose there aren't full tutorials out there. Maybe I'll just write on myself.

I won't pick your answer, although helpful, because it's not a tutorial. Thanks though!

Comment: jeweler is the only thing you need to start a new gem. everything is already setup for you on the `Rakefile`.